# Improve Feed readability

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app, fonts, android-app-feed

Since the latest update the android app's feed font changed. While the kerning is better and I personally like the lightweight L&F, I can see it becoming a problem on contrast-weak screens and for people who's eyes aren't the best anymore.

[image: Feed from android app, click to enlarge]

I'd love to have the blue of the font a tad darker and "bolder" to aid readability

Comment: I have the same concern. I was considering to post a discussion about the recent change about the font on the feed, since I don't think it's Roboto... or it's too thin, enough making me think like a different font at all. Worse, it's thinner than a comment reply on the feed.

Comment: It's Roboto. You're definitely right about the contrast though, I'm going to remove the blue tint from the background and try to up the text color a bit too.

Comment: @KasraRahjerdi - will be v. grateful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.0.69 (coming out in the next few days) the blue-ish white background is gone everywhere, which leads to both a simpler looking design and higher contrast. Here's what the feed looks like now:

[image: Feed]